# Windows photo viewer via command line - special features

Tags: windows, command-line, photo, viewer

I want to view a tiff file with Windows Photo Viewer under Windows 7 and Windows XP via command line execution.

Doing that is not the problem, but some special features I want to have.

1. I want to keep the photo viewer in the foreground, even when other programs get focus.
2. I want to disable the "Next" and "Previous picture"-buttons.
3. I want to have the possibility to open multiple instances of windows photo viewer.
4. Options 1-3 should be operative only for pictures I've opened via command line and not for pictures opened regularly.

Thank in advance.

Marco

Comment: What command line switches does Windows Photo Viewer have?

Comment: The only "switch" I know, is "ImageView_Fullscreen". ATM the command looks like `rundll32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen %1`

Answer (score -4):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll",ImageView_Fullscreen %1
```

send this command to

```
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe
```

Comment: Could you please provide a more detailed answer?