# How to open photo viewer in full screen

Tags: c#, windows

I need to view an image using windows photo viewer, I tried the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808029/open-image-in-windows-photo-viewer)

This code worked for me:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\MyPicture.jpg");
```

My question is, what parameters I should pass to open the image in fullscreen?

Comment: Your answer is in comments: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17991937/1207195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this -

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\MyPicture.jpg");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Note- There is no way to make it "Full Screen", this above code only "Maximizes".

[Link to a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743213/application-that-can-open-program-in-full-screen)

Comment: Same as [the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45819596/how-to-open-photo-viewer-in-full-screen#comment78596840_45819648): **Full-screen**, not _maximized_, they're different things. BTW there is a way, see  https://stackoverflow.com/q/17991937/1207195